# Characterization of line graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I'm confused about how you to recognize line graphs.

From [the Wikipedia page on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph#Characterization_and_recognition), I read that

> A graph is a line graph if and only if it does not contain one of
>   these nine graphs as an induced subgraph:
>
> [image: Forbidden line subgraphs]

Which explains why this graph is not a line graph as it induces a claw, which is one of the forbidden subgraph.

[image]

However here's a graph and its subgraph (in green). This line graph also contains a claw, if you look at the vertex (4,3) which is adjacent to (1,3), (1,4) and (4,5).

[image: a graph G]
[image: it's line graph]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say induced subgraph, we mean you choose some vertices and take **all** edges between them. So when you choose (4,3), (1,3), (1,4), and (4,5) you get a diamond (with an edge across its middle), not the claw.